# BitConverter.ToInt16 giving "Destination array is not long enough"

Tags: arrays, vb.net, byte, type-conversion

I am trying to convert an array of bytes into an array of shorts like this:

```
Public Sub mixFinal()
    Dim patch1Buffer(patch1.Length - 44) As Byte

    System.Array.Copy(patch1, 44, patch1Buffer, 0, patch1.Length - 44)

    Dim patch1ShortBuffer(patch1Buffer.Length) As Short

    For x = 0 To patch1Buffer.Length - 1 Step 1
        patch1ShortBuffer(x) = System.BitConverter.ToInt16(patch1Buffer, x)
    Next
End Sub
```

'patch1' is an array of bytes that is created by reading in a .wav file with the IO.File.ReadAllBytes method.

Visual Studio gives me this error when the program is compiled:

```
Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length.
```

I tried changing the sizes of 'patch1Buffer' and 'patch1ShortBuffer' to higher values but the error is still given... What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `short` size in `bytes` equals to 2 `bytes`.

Therefore, there are twice less shorts resulting when converting an array of bytes.

Following code will convert your array of bytes to shorts:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices ' for alternative

Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim bytes(1024-1) As Byte

        Dim shortSize = 2 ' alternative: shortCount = Marshal.SizeOf(GetType(Short))
        Dim shortCount = bytes.Length / shortSize

        Dim shorts(shortCount) as Short
        For i = 0 To shortCount-1
           shorts(i)= BitConverter.ToInt16(bytes, i*shortSize)
        Next

    End Sub

End Module
```

Answer (score 0):

OK so for I am going to assume here you are trying to convert single bytes into shorts.... in which case the bitconvertor.toint16 function will run off the end of the patch1buffer since it retrieves 2 bytes at a time.

Use

```
patch1ShortBuffer(x) = cShrt(patch1Buffer(x))
```

instead.

If you are trying to grab the pairs as uShorts you need to half the size of patch1ShortBuffer, iterate to it's length using x*2 for the ToInt16 call